# Moving a UIImage in a UITableViewCell based on row height

Tags: ios, uitableview

I have an image of a dashed line that is supposed to sit almost at the bottom of each of my `UITableViewCell`s. In the nib file, I have this line sitting at a y position of 40 pixels where the cell height is 44 pixels. In cases where the text requires more vertical space than that, I need to move that line down to correspond with the additional row height.

I'm able to calculate the row height easily enough, but I cannot seem to reposition the image. I have the following code in the subclass of `UITableViewCell`:

```
- (void) layoutSubviews {
    [super layoutSubviews];

    NSLog(@"before layout adjustment: %f", _imageDashedLine.frame.origin.y);

    CGRect lineFrame = _imageDashedLine.frame;
    lineFrame.origin.y += self.frame.size.height - 44.0f;
    [_imageDashedLine setFrame:lineFrame];

    NSLog(@"after layout adjustment: %f", _imageDashedLine.frame.origin.y);
}
```

Here is some of the output from this:

> before layout adjustment: 0.000000
>  after layout adjustment:
>   0.000000
>  before layout adjustment: 0.000000
>  after layout adjustment: 16.000000
>  before layout adjustment: 0.000000
>  after
>   layout adjustment: 16.000000
>  before layout adjustment:
>   0.000000
>  after layout adjustment: 0.000000
>  before layout adjustment: 0.000000
>  after layout adjustment: 16.000000

You can see that in some cases, I don't need to reposition the image, but in other cases I do. I'm able to determine the vertical distance that I need to move the image down by. However, in no cases is the image being repositioned when drawn. It just stays where it started, which screws up my cell display.

Can anyone see what I am doing wrong? Thanks!

Comment: Just a hunch but I wonder if it has to do with your `UITableVieCell`'s being reused. However, when I've seen issues like this it worked on some of the cells but not all which indicated the cells were cached and so adjustments didn't happen properly. Anyway, try a test where you instantiate a new cell every time instead of using cached cells and see if the line moves.

Answer (score 1):

If you are not using auto-layout, on your `UIImageVIew` in nib class of your `UITabelViewCell`, provide *left* and *bottom* position constraint from *Autosizing* box in *Size Inspection* tab. Now, the image will remain at bottom at any case.

If you are using auto-layout, then provide proper constraints for image to remain at bottom independent of changing cell height.

Comment: Thank you. I don't see an Autosizing box in the size inspector.

Comment: That is because, by default the auto-layout property is on. Open your nib file, from the right menu, select first tab and unselect check mark saying "Use Auto Layout"

Comment: After that, you will be able to change auto sizing properties.

Answer (score 0):

In the `prepareForReuse` method of you `UITableViewCell` subclass are you calling `setNeedsLayout`?

Comment: Thanks. That didn't seem to change anything.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to work. I'd love to hear if anyone has a better idea.

```
- (void) layoutSubviews {
    [super layoutSubviews];

    CGRect frame = _imageDashedLine.frame;

    [_imageDashedLine removeFromSuperview];

    frame.origin.y = self.frame.size.height - 4.0f;
    [_imageDashedLine setFrame:frame];

    [self addSubview:_imageDashedLine];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using some of the CGRect geometry methods. Have a look at CGRectOffset or CGRectInset.
You should be able to use one of these to track the table cell frame and keep the image in the same position relative to the bottom of the cell.